# Access controller / views instance variable in javascript or jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have following view file and I need to reference views instance variable in `.js.erb` file.

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table no-border">
      <% @leads.each_slice(2) do |slice| %>   
          <tr>
              <% slice.each do |lead| %>
                  <td class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="border: none;"> 

                      <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: solid  #E0E0E0 1px;">
                          <div class="panel-heading custom-panel-heading" style="background-color: #F0F0F0;"> 
                                  <%= form_for :email_form, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, url: search_reduce_credits_by1_path, id: "candidate-email-modal-form", remote: true do |f| %>

                                    <%= f.hidden_field :lead_id, :value => lead.id %>

                                    <div class=text-right>
                                      <%= f.button class: "btn btn-primary", id: "show-mail-btn" do %> 
                                        Show Email
                                      <% end %>
                                    </div>

                                    <small class="blurfilter" id="blurred_email_<%= lead.id %>" data-query="blurred_email_<%= lead.id %>"> <%= lead.email %> | <%= lead.id %></small>

                                  <% end %> 

                  </td>
              <% end %>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

How do I reference `<%= lead.id %>` in .js.erb file?

```
var x = $(".blurfilter").data("query");
alert(x);
```

Its not working as of now.

Comment: what do you mean by its not working, show us the output, if you are getting an error, paste the stack trace

Comment: It's giving 1 every time as alert, even if lead.id is different.

Answer (score 0):

If `lead` is instance variable i.e `@lead` then it should be directly accessible in your js.erb. file. In js.erb you can write it like this "<%= lead.id %>".